# snap-store not loading

Tags: snap-store

on ubuntu 20.10

```
$ snap-store
18:28:22:0379 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
18:28:22:0381 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
18:28:22:0404 Gs  enabled plugins: desktop-categories, fwupd, os-release, packagekit, packagekit-local, packagekit-offline, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-refresh, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, appstream, desktop-menu-path, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-popular, modalias, odrs, packagekit-refine, rewrite-resource, packagekit-history, provenance, snap, systemd-updates, generic-updates, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
18:28:22:0404 Gs  disabled plugins: dpkg, dummy, fedora-langpacks, fedora-pkgdb-collections, repos
18:28:22:0455 Gs  /etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf file not found
18:28:22:0646 Pango pango_font_get_hb_font: assertion 'PANGO_IS_FONT (font)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```